# dd4t-2-java Spring MVC web application "ComponentPresentationController"

Tags: dd4t

I am just new to DD4T and Tridion. We're trying to implement integration test for the components and I need someone help to explain how does the ComponentPresentationController work? I have a component name test.jsp and id is 1234

I'm trying to access the component in the URL http://localhost:8080/ww/en/test/1234.dcp according to the below method in the controller but it does not work. Can someone help me to understand how I could show that component? Thanks

```
@Override
@RequestMapping (value = {"/{componentViewName}/{componentId}.dcp"}, 
                 method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
public String showComponentPresentation (@PathVariable final String componentViewName, 
                                         @PathVariable final int componentId, 
                                         final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return super.showComponentPresentation(componentViewName, componentId, request);
}
```